# How to set a specific color as my default player color in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

A search on [our forum](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=how%20to%20set%20a%20specific%20color%20as%20my%20default%20player%20color%20in%20Starcraft%202%3F), and [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20set%20a%20specific%20color%20as%20my%20default%20player%20color%20in%20Starcraft%202%3F&oq=how%20to%20set%20a%20specific%20color%20as%20my%20default%20player%20color%20in%20Starcraft%202%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.738j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) on this topic get me nowhere.

So how can I set my default player color?

p.s.

Hitting Alt-F will switch player colors into red for enemy, yellow for allies, and green for self - NOT what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

It is only possible to choose your color in Custom Games or Arcade, but not in Matchmaking.